# AngularJS Как сгруппировать данные - GroupBy

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(dt, inf) in items | groupBy:'date'">
     {{toDate(dt)}}
      <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="event in inf">
        {{event.name}}:{{event.lastname}}
       </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Возвращает:

```
05.11.2017
ivan : ivanovich
06.11.2017
oleg : olegovich
06.11.2017
vladimir : vladimirovich
07.11.2017
denis : denisovich
```

Контроллер:

```
$http.get('/user/info/')
   .success(function(data){
     $scope.items = data;
   }

// Функция для конвертации даты 
$scope.toDate = function(unix_timestamp) {
                var options_date = {
                    year: 'numeric',
                    month: 'numeric',
                    day: 'numeric'
                };
                var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
                    return date.toLocaleString("ru", options_date);
                };    

app.filter('groupBy', function() {
           return _.memoize(function(items, field) {
                   return _.groupBy(items, field);
               }
           );
       });
```

В `$scope.items` хранится:

```
{date:"1509882662", name:"ivan", lastname:"ivanovich"}
{date:"1509955337", name:"oleg", lastname:"olegovich"}
{date:"1509959921", name:"vladimir", lastname:"vladimirovich"}
{date:"1510081026", name:"denis", lastname:"denisovich"}
```

Как довести ответ до вида:

```
07.11.2017
denis : denisovich

06.11.2017
oleg : olegovich
vladimir : vladimirovich

05.11.2017
ivan : ivanovich
```

Comment: добавь пример того, что в items хранится

Comment: Подредактировал вопрос!

Comment: разное выводит, потому что он в groupBy получает числа `1509955337`, `1509959921` а не даты

Comment: А реально ему в groupBy через функцию toDate сделать запрос?

Comment: так, а groupBy сторонний используется?

Comment: в принципе ничего не мешает передавать твой `toDate` в фильтр, и использовать его

Comment: А можно пример? Хочу понять в контроллере или в представление использовать)

Comment: в принципе и там и там можно, проще в контроллере

Comment: Не совсем понятно куда его вставлять)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ: добавить нужное поле с датой в объекты получаемой коллекции.

Далее просто использовать его и для группировки и для вывода.

Например:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout, $filter) {
    var groubBy = $filter('groupBy');
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.items = [{
        date: "1509882662",
        name: "ivan",
        lastname: "ivanovich"
      }, {
        date: "1509955337",
        name: "oleg",
        lastname: "olegovich"
      }, {
        date: "1509959921",
        name: "vladimir",
        lastname: "vladimirovich"
      }, {
        date: "1510081026",
        name: "denis",
        lastname: "denisovich"
      }];
      $scope.items.forEach(function(el) {
        el['dt'] = toDate(el['date'])
      });
    }, 500);
    // Функция для конвертации даты 
    function toDate(unix_timestamp) {
      var options_date = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric'
      };
      var date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
      return date.toLocaleString("ru", options_date);
    };
  }).filter('groupBy', function() {
    return _.memoize(function(items, field) {
      return _.groupBy(items, field);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <li ng-repeat="(dt, inf) in items | groupBy:'dt'">
    {{dt}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="event in inf">
        {{event.name}}:{{event.lastname}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```